# cv::KalmanFilter not working [Solved]

Tags: ros, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use kalman filter in ROS with OpenCV library, but I'm getting error.

below is the error that I'm getting while compilation.

error: ‘KalmanFilter’ is not a member of ‘cv’
cv::KalmanFilter kf(stateSize, measSize, contrSize, type);
^
/home/pkumars/catkin_ws/src/cv_bridge_tutorial_pkg/src/kalman_code1.cpp:59:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘kf’
cv::KalmanFilter kf(stateSize, measSize, contrSize, type);
^

and here is my code that I'm trying to compile.

```
// ROS synchronization headers
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
// ROS headers
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
// OpenCV headers
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
// c++ headers
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>  
// pcl headers
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
// visualization header
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>

// point cloud definition
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;

// standard namespace for c++, ROS messages transport, ROS message filters, OpenCV 
using namespace std;
using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;
using namespace cv;


// Kalman filter parameters 
int stateSize = 6;          // 6 no of states 
int measSize = 3;           // 3 parameters to be measured 
int contrSize = 0;          // 
unsigned int type = CV_32F; // type
```

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )

{

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "prediction_node");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ROS_INFO("Starting ");
    
cv::KalmanFilter kf(stateSize, measSize, contrSize, type);

ros::spin();
return 0;
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227655/cv::kalmanfilter-not-working-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are already using namespace cv, so you don't have to write cv:: infront of your methods.
That won't cause an error, but just nice to know.

The KalmanFilter is in the #include "tracking.hpp", and i can't see that you have included that, so try to do that and see if it still gives an error.

Here is a sample code of how to use it:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/kalman.cpp

---

Originally posted by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) with karma: 92 on 2016-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-02-26**:
it worked.  Thanks a lot..

**Comment by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) on 2016-02-26**:
Please flag it as solved and upvote if the problem is solved ;)